# Selecting users based on their skills along with matched skills in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, many-to-many, laravel-query-builder

I want to search in my database for Users based on their Skills. Then I want to get the User profiles where the skills are matched.

### My Database Migrations

#### users

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->string('password');
```

#### skills

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name');
```

#### user_skill

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
$table->unsignedInteger('skill_id');
```

Here are my models:-

## User.php

```
public function skill(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'user_skill');
}
```

The User and Skill models have a Many to Many Relationship.

Now, I have written a query that selects Users from "user" table based on their skills. My query looks like this:-

```
$skills = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"];
$result = User::with('skill')
    ->join('user_skill', 'users.id','=','user_skill.user_id')
    ->join('skills', 'user_skill.skill_id', '=', 'skills.id')
    ->select('users.name as Name','users.id as UserId')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(skills.id) as skill_count')
    ->whereIn('skills.name', $skills)
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->orderBy('skill_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

This query gives me the following result, after some formatting:-
[image: The result of query]

But I want to get the users, along with their skills. Every user in the given screenshot has about 5 skills. The **with('skill')** clause is supposed to return the Users along with their Skills. But when I put the result in a foreach loop,

```
foreach($result as $r){
    print_r($r->skill);
}
```

The skill field is empty. The laravel with() clause was supposed to inject skills along with the users since they have a many to many relationship. Is there something I did wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Note:
When I query **User::with('skill')->get()** it returns all the users with skills. So, I suppose the relational binding is good here.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = User::whereHas('skills'=>function($query){
  $query->whereIn('name', ['css', 'html', 'javascript']);
})->withCount('skills')
->select('users.name as Name','users.id as UserId')
->groupBy('users.id')
->orderBy('skill_count', 'desc')
->get();
```

as you are grouping the results, I don't think there will a need for the join statements. and you can achieve all the things you want in the simpler code, above. also, as another user mentioned, look out for typos.

Answer (score 0):

I presume it is empty since you seem to have a typo on your query, instead of `with('skills')` you have written it skill, while joining you used the right column name.

So fix that:

```
$result = User::with('skills')
    ->join('user_skill', 'users.id','=','user_skill.user_id')
    ->join('skills', 'user_skill.skill_id', '=', 'skills.id')
    ->select('users.name as Name','users.id as UserId')
    ->selectRaw('COUNT(skills.id) as skill_count')
    ->whereIn('skills.name', $skills)
    ->groupBy('users.id')
    ->orderBy('skill_count', 'desc')
    ->get();
```